# How to record stdout and stderr with different tags in syslog?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, redirection

I can redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to `logger` [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677265/3516684):

```
./myprog 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty | logger
```

but I would like to be able to **tag** each log entry with "`myprog-out`" and "`myprog-err`" based on where it came from (`stdout` and `stderr` respectively).

I would also like to be able to see both stdout and stderr output on screen.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you have [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) features available, you can use [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) to redirect each stream individually like you would with plain files:

```
./myprog  > >(logger -t myprog-out)  2> >(tee /dev/tty | logger -t myprog-err)
```

Comment: this is very close to what I need, but as-is I only see stderr on screen but not stdout (they both log to syslog as required)

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112979/pipe-stdout-and-stderr-to-two-different-processes-in-shell-script

You can replace the sed with logger -t *tag* commands to get them to go into system log files.

Here's what I did with the sample script in the above URL:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    echo a
    echo b >&2
    echo c
    echo d >&2
    }

{ foo 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | logger -t 'my-err'; } 3>&1 1>&2 | logger -t 'my-stdout'

exit 0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this seems to be working too: `{ ./foo 2>&3 | logger -t my-out; } 3>&1 1>&2 | logger -t my-err`. what's the function of `2>&1 1>&3 3>&-` in your answer?

Comment: I was following what was in the URL.  It was saying you needed to temporarily redirect stdout to a different file descriptor to avoid mixing stderr and stdout.

Comment: any idea how to also still maintain both on screen while logging them?

Comment: You could do a "tee /dev/tty | logger" in lieu of just logger.  That might work.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the answer below, but came across an issue which may be relevant to the other answers, as well as to problems which don't use `logger`, with its tag option, so I'll submit my findings.

First, I generated mixed standard output and error messages, with some gaps between them with:

```
echo abc; sleep 1; echo def >&2; sleep 1; echo ghi; sleep 1; echo jkl >&2
```

Then I added `out:` to the front of the standard output messages with:

```
{ echo abc; sleep 1; echo def >&2; sleep 1; echo ghi; sleep 1; echo jkl >&2; } | \
    sed 's/^/out: /g';
```

I then added `err:` to the error stream by adding to all records, then removing the `out:` strings already added (note that whatever string is used for `out:` must not start any unmodified error record):

```
{ { echo abc; sleep 1; echo def >&2; sleep 1; echo ghi; sleep 1; echo jkl >&2; } | \
    sed 's/^/out: /g'; } 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/err: /g' -e 's/^err: out: /out: /g'
```

Lewis M's answer suggests that it might be possible to use redirection to stream 3 to avoid the double substitution, but this works fine with the constraint above; however, buffering means that the records are not necessarily recorded in the order in which they were generated, so I finished up with:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 bash -c \
    "{ { echo abc; sleep 1; echo def >&2; sleep 1; echo ghi; sleep 1; echo jkl >&2; } | \
    sed 's/^/out: /g'; } 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/err: /g' -e 's/^err: out: /out: /g'" | \
    tee /dev/tty | logger
```

This runs the previous command in a unbuffered environment, then pipes the output through `tee`, so that it is seen on the console, then on to the logger.